# Modeling a cylindrical object to resemble an image reference

Tags: modeling, topology

I'm trying un-successfuly to model the cylinderical shape in the reference image. I tried simple deform, But that results in pinching artifacts. unlike basic circle model. Please how can I make it the right way? With right workflow. Thanks
[image]

Comment: I believe the best way is to use Boolean intersection using small cylinders to carve the edges, or using BoolTool addon, which will give you more freedom editing the Boolean operation before applying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Model the main object and the shape to use for Boolean modifier.
[image]
2- Select the main object, in Modifiers panel, add a Boolean modifier, assign the object you want to extract under (Object) in Boolean modifier.
[image]
3- Choose Difference as the Method, then Apply the modifier.
4- Delete the extraction object or move it to another layer.
[image]

The disadvantage of this method is that it'll create Ngons, yet since this a radial symmetrical object, you can model 1/8th of the object first, use the Boolean modifier and apply it, fix the Ngons by connecting vertices using <kbd>J</kbd> or using knife tool <kbd>K</kbd>, then copy rotate it 45 degrees, in order to get the whole object.

Comment: thks for your solution sir....

Comment: You are most welcome :)